# Requesting information from one php file to another using only php

Tags: php

I am pretty new to php so I'm having trouble with POSTing.
I am trying to transfer information between 2 php files where send_var.php sends a command by POST and get_var.php executes some data manipulation and returns the response.
The send_var.php is as follows:

```
<?php
$url = "./get_var.php";
$fields = array('response' => "323243");
$data = http_build_query($fields);
// echo $data."<br />";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => "Content-type: text/html\r\n",
    'content' => $data
),
));
$out = file_get_contents($url, false, $context); 
echo "Info from get_var : " . $out;
?>
```

And the get_var.php is :

```
<?php
$arg1 = isset($_POST['response']) ? $_POST['response'] : null;
if($arg1 == '')
    {
    echo "No Command! ";
    }
if($arg1 != "")
    {
    echo $_POST['response'];
    }
else
    {
    $_POST['response'] = "123456";
    echo $_POST['response'] . " end of get_var";
    }
?>
```

This code was extracted from other examples on stack overflow. The only output I get is "Info from get_var :"
Obviously I'm missing some pretty fundamental knowledge. If someone can help it would be much appreciated. I'm executing this under XAMPP.

Comment: Dont you looking for `include`? Fill the code into function and call it.

Comment: file_get_contents will only post data to a url. You have provided a filepath. change $url to mywebsite.com/get_var.php and your good to go

Answer (score 2):

In order to run a PHP script, you have to access it through the webserver. So the URL needs to be an `http:` URL, not just a filename:

```
$url = "http://localhost/path/to/get_var.php";
```

If you just use a filename, `file_get_contents()` will just return the PHP source code, it won't run it.

Also, your `Content-type` header is wrong, it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `text/html` (that's the content type of the response, your context specifies the type of the `POST` data).

Comment: In the end send_var and get_var may be on separate servers. I added $url = "http://localhost:8090/c:/javascript/projects/hrminteractive/get_var.php"; but it didn't find get_var.php. XAMPP is the server, It's default path points to the folder specified.

Comment: I changed $url = "http://localhost:8090/get_var.php"; Now it get's a response but the $_POST['response'] is not set so I get the alternate response: Info from get_var : No Command! 123456 end of get_var

Comment: Barmar Thanks so much, changing the content-type that fixed it. Regards